# Best way to add class to parent of radio item, remove and add class

Tags: jquery, selector

quick question regarding jQuery and improving my code.

Basically upon the selection of a radio button I am adding a select class to the parent container, in this instance the list item. Removing the select class from the previously selected item upon change.

I cannot help but feel that there is a better way to compact and clean the code below.

```
$('#fubar input[name=game]').change(function(){
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('selected');
})
```

Thank you for your help :) much appreciated.

Comment: I write this exact code once a week.  Something simpler would be nice (and you could make some very small perf improvements at the cost of code legibility by providing a ) but this is generally how it is done.  No idea why people are offering `closest`, other than it may save you some code later on if your structure changes.

Comment: @JohnGreen closest is used if li is not the direct parent of your input. If you have `<li><label><input>...` then parent won't work anymore (or you'll have to parent().parent().parent()...), but closest() will.

Comment: @PierreGranger - Like I stated.. it may save him some code later if his structure changes (as it doesn't appear to be a problem now).  I was simply suggesting that isn't germane to the question of whether or not the code was compact/clean.

Comment: You know the difference but maybe not @karen_west, so it's preferable to explain why some prefer cloest ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // this detects the change event as it propagates through to the
  // <li> element:
  $('li').on('change', function() {
    // adds the 'selected' class-name to the <li> that
    // holds the changed <input> (the change event is 
    // fired only on checking the <input>):
    $(this).addClass('selected')
    // selects the siblings of the <li>:
    .siblings()
    // removes the 'selected' class-name from those siblings:
    .removeClass('selected');
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('li').on('change', function() {
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
  });
});
```

```css
li {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li.selected {
  border-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="fubar">
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="game" />One</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="game" />Two</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="game" />Three</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="game" />Four</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Similar to the above, but this version first selects the relevant `<input />` elements whose `change` event you want to detect:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // selects the <input> elements whose type is equal to 'radio'
  // and whose name is equal to 'game':
  $('input[type=radio][name=game]')
  // looks to the closest <li> ancestor of those <input> elements:
  .closest('li')
  // as above from this point:
  .on('change', function() {
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=radio][name=game]').closest('li').on('change', function() {
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
  });
});
```

```css
li {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li.selected {
  border-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="fubar">
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="game" />One</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="game" />Two</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="game" />Three</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="game" />Four</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

References:

- CSS:

  - Attribute selectors.
- jQuery:

  - [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
  - [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).
  - [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

Comment: siblings... so classy, never though about it :|

Comment: I've not tested it cross-browser, but the change event propagates in Chrome 35.x (on Windows 7).

Comment: Nice detailed answer.  I hate the first example (taking all LIs like that), but I can get down with the 2nd.  I'd probably do the closest inside of the change closure though:  `($this).closest('li').addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');`.  The closest doesn't get cached, but you don't have to wait for a bubble, or pay the load cost for that second order filter.  In the end, that kind of microoptimization may even save 2ms.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#fubar input[name=game]').change(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    $this.closest('ul').find($('.selected')).removeClass('selected');
    $this.closest('li').addClass('selected');
})
```

Only what can you change is `.parent` to `.closest` - but your solution looks ok,

Comment: Just maybe `$(this).closest('ul').find('li').removeClass('selected')`, to make sure it won't remove selected on other li in other ul.

Comment: Not on your first line, where you remove class. Your remove class on any element with .selected, anywhere in the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try `closest()` and `find()`:

```
$('#fubar').find('input[name=game]').on('change', function(){
    $('#fubar').find('li.selected').removeClass('selected');//selector changed
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('selected');//used `closest()`
})
```

From [docs](https://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/):

> // Fast: $( "#container div.robotarm" );
>   // Super-fast: $(
>   "#container" ).find( "div.robotarm" );

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to toggle class for both elements you want to change (this would be shorter):

```
$(this).closest('li').add('.selected').toggleClass('selected');
```

Comment: wut ? what is this supposed to do ? :|

Comment: $(this).closest('li').add('.selected') - jQuery wrapper over clicked and currently selected. Then toggle class 'selected' for both of them (remove if exists and add if not exists).